# DotNetNuke Add/Manage New Role Issue

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I am running DOTNETNUKE Version 07.01.00 (2676) and for some reason when I got to 
USERS|Manage Roles|Add New Role it just hangs. I am able to modify users and roles that already exist just unable add a new security role.

Are there any settings I can check to see why this is not working? I have read in some cases this could be a DB related issue. I have two identical environments and they are both doing the exact same thing. This is a recent upgrade to 07.01.00 (2676).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any other issues?

I would check a couple of things.

1) On your HOST/HOST SETTINGS page check if you have "Hosted" jquery selected, if so, try unchecking it.

2) Any errors in the EventLog?

3) If you open the developer toolbar in your browser, any errors being thrown when you click on that option?

Comment: From what I can tell i'm not having any other issues.

JQuery was selected and i unchecked it but it still does not work

no errors in the event logs

I don't have any developer tools installed so i'm unable to test like this

Comment: Press F12 (might be Control-Shift-i) in your browser, then click on the "console" option to see if that shows you any errors.

Comment: I just tried it and i do see 4 errors but they have to do with 404 not found on footer images. What other setting should i check?

Comment: Do you think this has to do with our Skin? We had a custom skin created for us as well and did the update to  07.01.00 (2676). at the same time

Edit: I just checked a site with the old version and old skin and it appears to be working

Comment: What if you choose another skin for that page and try it out?

Comment: I tried to do that and still no luck. It seems like its the version of DNN that is having issues?

Comment: I just tested one of my DNN 7.1 installs and adding a role worked fine. Are you able to EDIT html modules, and save the changes?

Comment: I just did the exact same thing with a new install and the Manage Roles worked fine. I am able to Edit html modules and save them. Could this be related to the DB since its happening in both environments?

Comment: It could be DB, it could be javascript, it really is hard to say at this point